# Can't run code on geany. Cannot execute build command

Tags: c++, fedora, xterm, geany

I installed geany on Fedora.
It compiles and builds my c++ code but it can't run the code.

"Cannot execute build command "xterm -e "/bin/sh /tmp/geany_run_script_BJ09E0.sh"": No such file or directory. Check the Terminal setting in Preferences"

I'm new on Linux and i don't know how to properly set terminal settings.

Comment: Well, the error is fairly explanatory `geany_run_script_BJ09E0.sh` can't be found. The question is whether that is the script that is used to launch the compiled executable? Honestly, I never had much use for an IDE running my code for me. Just open another xterm and `cd` to the directory where geany is outputting the executable, and just run your program from the command line. I would encourage reporting the problem to [Geany on github](https://github.com/geany/geany) so they can determine if it is a geany or Fedora packaging problem (I suspect the latter)

Comment: (that said, geany is one of my favorite code editors -- especially the Gtk+2 version)

Comment: Have you check the terminal settings? Is xterm installed?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your spin, bring different Console Emulators.

For example, Fedora with KDE comes with **konsole** terminal emulator.
To use konsole with Geany, configure Edit - Preferences - Tools -> 
**Terminal:** `konsole -e "/bin/sh %c"`

But, if you still want to use the **xterm** emulator (lighter and faster), you can install it from the repository, leaving Geany with the default configuration.

```
sudo dnf install xterm
```